# IBM Softlayer Object Storage: Is encryption at rest (as a service) an option?

Tags: encryption, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage, ibm-cloud-storage

I am currently using IBM Softlayer Object Storage.  I'm wondering whether there is some encryption at rest (as a service) option?  For example, does Softlayer manage encryption keys in some way (the way AWS does for instance with I AM), or does it provide an easy way to automatically encrypt what is uploaded through the Object Storage API?

Answer (score 1):

What I know there is not such way to automatically encrypt the data uploaded, you need to encrypt your data prior to upload it.

Just in case you can look for documentation which could help you here: http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/objectstorageapi

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Not a good question for SO, but for education's sake there is a new public cloud IBM Object Storage that is based on Cleversafe, and all data is encrypted at rest by default.

Comment: Nick, can you share a link to this service?

Comment: For sure, here's the overview: https://www.ibm.com/cloud-computing/products/storage/object-storage/ and here is the documentation: https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/index.html